# If transaction has impossible locking script, are coins lost?

Tags: script, lost-bitcoins, locktime

If a bitcoin transaction's outputs have a locking script that is basically unsolvable, are the bitcoins lost, or can the transaction be invalidated?  (Or something else?)

Comment: If you are trying to do this on purpose, just set the `scriptPubKey` to `OP_RETURN` and nothing else.  This makes the transaction provably unspendable:  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Provably_Unspendable.2FPrunable_Outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it made it into the blockchain, meaning 1 confirmation or more, it practically can't be invalidated. The same feature prevents people from reversing payments.

If it's provably unsolvable, then there's no way to spend the coins, and they're practically destroyed.